# Snowflake micropartitions in case of inserts

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How does micro partitions of snowflake works if we are inserting the data one by one in table and if we are loading the whole file?
Will the number of micro partitions increases in case of loading the data one by one using inserts as compared to load the data from files?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the purpose of the question is, but it is obviously MUCH better to batch load your file, rather than do individual record inserts, not just because of your question, but also because of the actual load performance.

As for your question, Snowflake will determine that if it has a single-record micropartition and you are inserting 1 additional record, it will create a new 2-record micropartition (assuming they aren't very large records).  So, the active table won't have more micropartitions per se, but you will still have that single-record micropartition as part of your time-travel and fail-safe.  So, if you were to do this 1 record at a time, over and over again, you'd have a lot of extra micropartitions to pay for.

Single-record inserts are just not a good idea in Snowflake.  It's worth looking into ways to batch them up and load them in bulk.

Comment: but microspartitioning start after some time , it will rearrange all the new records into micropartition ,even in bulk insert it has to go record by record for rearrangement. So isn't the same case for loading in bulk or in few records.?

Comment: That is all done in the warehouse before creating the micropartition, if you are talking about compression and columnarization.  If you are referring to clustering, that is done by a service after the fact and really doesn't relate to this question.

Comment: My question is that in snowflake the data is stored in micro partitions so for eg if we are loading 1000 rows with insert statements and loading the same 1000 rows from file then which case will have more micro partitions file or insert one

Comment: If you are inserting 1000 rows in 1 bulk insert statement vs. `COPY INTO` from a file, then the micropartition count will be the same.  If you are inserting 1 record at a time, 1000 times, then my answer above.